# How does the 0-1 metric not work for all spaces?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I learned there are non-metrizable topological spaces. I don't understand, however, how the following metric could fail to work for *any* topological space:
$$d(x,y) = \cases{0 & if $x=y$ \\
                                1 & otherwise}$$
How does it not satisfy the metric axioms? I can't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that a topological space is metrizable if there is a metric such that it generates *the specific topology we are talking about*, not *some* topology.

Comment: +1. Clarification for the OP: a *metric* $d$ on a set $X$ induces a *topology* $\tau_d$ on $X$ - the "open sets" in the topological sense are exactly the "open sets" in the metric sense. Now, the "discrete" metric you describe always induces the *discrete topology* (every set is open); so if $(X, \tau)$ is a *non*-discrete topological space, the discrete metric on $X$ won't work for showing that $(X,\tau)$ is metrizable (we need a $d$ with $\tau_d=\tau$).